# Uniform convergence on open interval and compact subintervals

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm looking at the question of uniform convergence for the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{n} (\tan(x))^n$ where $x \in [0,\pi/4)$.

I showed uniform convergence for $0 \leq x \leq a< \pi/4$ using the M-test because $\sqrt{n}(\tan(x))^n\leq \sqrt{n}(\tan(a))^n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{n}(\tan(a))^n$ converges by the ratio test.

I think convergence is not uniform on the half-open interval $[0,\pi/4$). How can this be shown? A related question: is non-pointwise convergence at  $x=b$ sufficient that convergence is not uniform on an open interval $(a,b)$ even when the convergence is uniform on all subintervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two useful observations:

> Let $(f_n)$ and $f$ be $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions on a set $E$. Suppose that $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $E$. Then
>
> 1. $f_n \to f$ pointwise on $E$, and
> 2. if each $f_n$ is bounded, then $f$ is also bounded.

Now assume otherwise that the sum converges uniformly on all of $[0, \pi/4)$. Then its uniform limit coincides with the pointwise limit, which we can bound from below by

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{n}\tan^n(x) \geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \tan^n(x) = \frac{\tan(x)}{1-\tan(x)}. $$

But this lower bound diverges as $x\uparrow \pi/4$, and so, the sum is not bounded on $[0, \pi/4)$. This contradicts the above observation, and so, the convergence cannot be uniform on $[0, \pi/4)$.

Comment: @SangculLee: Thank you! I had a feeling there was a general principle like this but could not pin it down.